# Find the unit-energy for $\mathrm{rect}(t/T)$?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, continuous-signals, signal-energy

My book says:

> The width-1 NRZ pulse is
> $$
> \mathrm{rect} (t) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1 , \qquad -1/2 \leq t \leq 1/2\\
> 0, \qquad \mathrm{otherwise} \tag 1
> \end{cases}
> $$
> The unit-energy width-$T$ NRZ pulse is
> $$
> \frac{1}{\sqrt T} \mathrm{rect}(\frac{t}{T}) \tag 2
> $$

I need help who to derive the unit-energy.

With $\mathrm{rect}(t/T)$ I think it is the function
$$
\mathrm{rect}(t/T) = 
\begin{cases}
1 , \qquad -T/2 \leq t \leq T/2\\
0, \qquad \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The energy is definition as
$
E = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert x(t) \rvert^2 \, dt 
$, so
$$
E = \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} \lvert \mathrm{rect}(t/T) \rvert^2 \, dt = \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} 1^2 \, dt 
= \frac{T}{2}-(-\frac{T}{2}) = T
$$
And we want unit-energy so $E=1$, but I don't know how to proceed. How can I find $(2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the book is saying. There is nothing like a "unit-energy" that you can compute. There is, however, a "unit-energy [...] pulse", which is a pulse with energy equal to $1$. So if you have some pulse $p(t)$ with energy

$$E_p=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|p(t)|^2dt\tag{1}$$

and you want to normalize it such that its energy becomes unity, you simply have to scale it by $1/\sqrt{E_p}$, which gives you the corresponding unit-energy pulse

$$\tilde{p}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{E_p}}p(t)\tag{2}$$

with energy

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\tilde{p}(t)|^2dt=\frac{1}{E_p}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|p(t)|^2dt=1\tag{3}$$

as expected.

Comment: Thank you, it clarified some things! But why is the scaling factor $1/\sqrt{E_p}$? I.e. can we derive $(2)$ somehow? I can't get a sense of $(2)$ by intuition.

Comment: @JDoeDoe: Any constant scaling factor $c$ applied to a function shows up as $c^2$ in the energy (because we integrate over the square of the function). So by scaling with $c$, the energy is multiplied by $c^2$. If I have a pulse with energy $E_p$ and I want to scale it such that its energy becomes $1$, I need to scale the pulse by $1/\sqrt{E_p}$ such that the energy gets scaled by $1/E_p$.